# Convert characters in string to numeric fixed positions ,2|4|6| needs to be ,020406

Tags: mysql, regex, csv, notepad++, cpanel

I have many files that need to be altered in order to import into cpanel, mysql. The number pattern is layout out like ,2|5|7|31|37|43|5
To import the file into the correct field, the data needs to be in format of 02050731374305

Is it better to just use notepad++ and edit all the files or is there a better way to import this data? Mysql field only allows numeric and is limited to 14 digits on this particular file.

The files I have are pretty much alike but vary in length. There are only 2 columns total in the file to import into mysql, cpanel.

reg expression might work but I have been finding errors on the replacement as it is picking up other numbers in the row and changing the data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that actually describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title simply repeats the information that is already contained in the tags you used (every single word), so it conveys nothing. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to be useful to a future site user who is scanning a list of search results trying to find a solution to their problem. Thanks.

Comment: i doubt that notepad++ will work that good with such a string, but regular programming languages can split your stirng and set it backtogehther without a problem. this could also be done in a function or stored procedure, but for that you need to give some table to play with

Comment: If it matters, this is a 'string' pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I a said a fucntion, that breaks the string and build the new one, will help you

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `new_function`(fullstr TEXT, delim char(1)) RETURNS char(16) CHARSET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE inipos INTEGER;
DECLARE endpos INTEGER;
DECLARE maxlen INTEGER;
DECLARE item VARCHAR(100);

SET inipos = 1;
SET @temptxt = '';
SET fullstr = CONCAT(fullstr,delim);
SET maxlen = LENGTH(fullstr) ;

REPEAT
    SET endpos = LOCATE(delim, fullstr, inipos);
    SET item =  SUBSTR(fullstr, inipos, endpos - inipos);

    IF item <> '' AND item IS NOT NULL THEN           
        SET @temptxt = CONCAT(@temptxt,LPAD(item,2,'0'));
    END IF;
    SET inipos = endpos + 1;
UNTIL inipos >= maxlen END REPEAT;
RETURN @temptxt;
END/7
DELIMITER ;
```

So you can

```
SELECT new_function('2|5|7|31|37|43|5','|')
```

And get

```
02050731374305
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution using `awk`:

```
echo "2|5|7|31|37|43|5" | awk -F'|' '{printf("%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)}'
02050731374305
```

Comment: While that sounds like a great solution, I have 100k+ rows throughout the 150+ files. If I must enter the echo on each one, I think it would be simpler to modify each column. Here is 7 rows of the first file example                                                                                                 27-05-2020,,18|21|27|31|38|52|2
23-05-2020,,6|18|22|32|35|51|3
20-05-2020,,27|34|41|45|48|50|5
16-05-2020,,9|10|22|27|32|44|2
13-05-2020,,5|15|18|34|37|47|4
09-05-2020,,6|23|32|33|42|49|5

Comment: The echo was just for the sake of testing the example line you gave. You can use `awk` to process the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with Notepad++, using the power of lookaround.

This will add  a zero before each digit alone and it works for any number of values:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!\d)(?=\d(?!\d))`
- Replace with: `0`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!            # negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't before:
  \d              # a digit
)               # end lookbehind
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
  \d              # digit
  (?!\d)          # not followed by another digit
)               # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]